# An Abstract Characterization of $S_5$ using involutions and their centralizers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

This is essentially an exercise from Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I*. (p.83, ex.10)

[image]

I've managed to solve all the other part of the proof, except (vi) and (x). I've been thinking about this all day, but couldn't get an satisfactory answer.

In (vi), I don't see why there exists $H$ with $C(P)\subset H$ with 36 elements in it. What happens if $N(P)$ has 72 elements?

Finally, in (x), I don't see why the action of $G$ on the coset space is effective. For a given $g\neq 1$ does there exist some element $x$ of $G$ such that the coset $xN(V)$ is not fixed by $g$?. I don' understand why this is the case.

Some help would be nice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For (vi) you can use $N_G(P)/C_G(P)\le Aut(P) = Z_2$.

Comment: Hint for (x): Assuming that Jacobson calls "effective action" what otherwise is known as "faithful action", you can try to show that the kernel $K$ of this action is a *proper* subgroup of $N_G(V)$, that is centralized by an element of order $5$ (look at $Aut(K))$, so cannot contain elements of order $2$. Then lead $K=Z_3$ normal in $G$ to a contradiction.

Comment: Clearer hint for (vi): If $|N_G(P)| = 36$ take $H=N_G(P)$, otherwise take $H=C_G(P)$ which has index $2$ in $N_G(P)$ as $N_G(P)/C_G(P) = Z_2$ ($C_1$ contains a nontrivial automorphism of $P$ and by my first comment there are no others).

Answer (score 0):

For item (vi):

Let $P=\{1,p,p^{-1}\}\subseteq C_1$. Because $C_1\cong Z_2\times S_3$, it is easy to see that $P$ is the unique subgroup of $C_1$ of order $3$, because there are only $3$ elements whose orders divide $3$, and that $C_1\nsubseteq C(P)$.

If $|N(P)|=72$, then $G=N(P)$, so for every $x\in G\setminus C(P)$ we have $xPx^{-1}=P$, but $xpx^{-1}\neq 1$ and $xpx^{-1}\neq p$, because $xpx^{-1}=p$ would imply $xp^{-1}x^{-1}=p^{-1}$, so $x\in C(P)$; therefore $xpx^{-1}=p^{-1}$. The converse is easy because $p^{-1}\neq p$. So $G\setminus C(P)$ is the set of $x\in G$ such that $xpx^{-1}=p^{-1}$. It is easy to see that $C(P)\neq G$, indeed, try to find an element $a\in C_1\setminus C(P)$.

Consider the function $F:G\rightarrow G$ such that $F(x)=axa^{-1}$. Then $F$ is a permutation of $G$, and $F[C(P)]=G\setminus C(P)$, so that $|C(P)|=\frac{72}{2}=36$.

For item (x):

Let $K$ the kernel of the action of $G$ on $G/H$. It easy to see that $|K|\mid|N(V)|=24$. We have some cases:

1. If $|K|=24$, then $K=N(V)$, so $u_1\in K$ and $u_2\in K$, but $K$ is a normal subgroup, so $K$ has all conjugates of $u_1$ and $u_2$. There are $\frac{|G|}{|C(u_1)|}=\frac{120}{12}=10$ conjugates of $u_1$ and there are $\frac{|G|}{|C(u_2)|}=\frac{120}{8}=15$ conjugates of $u_2$. Moreover the conjugates of $u_1$ and the conjugates of $u_2$ form disjoint sets. Therefore $|K|\geq 10+15=25>24$, contradiction.
2. If $2\mid|K|$, then $K$ has an involution $u$, so it has every conjugate of $u$. Because $u$ is conjugate to either $u_1$ or $u_2$, then either $u_1\in K$ or $u_2\in K$.

2,1) If $u_2\in K$, then because there are $15$ conjugates of $u_2$ we have $|K|\geq 15$, but $|K|\mid 24$, so $|K|=24$ and by case (1) we reach a contradiction.

2,2) If $u_1\in K$, then because of item (iii), $u_1u_2$ is conjugate to $u_1$, so $u_1u_2\in K$, so $u_2=u_1^{-1}(u_1u_2)\in K$, and by case (2,1) we reach a contradiction.

3. If $|K|=3$, then $K$ is a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G$, so because all Sylow $3$-subgroups are conjugate to each other (by Sylow's Theorems), then there is only one subgroup of $G$ order $3$. Looking at $C_1\cong Z_2\times S_3$, then there is a unique subgroup of $C_1$ of order $3$, so $K\subseteq C_1=C(u_1)$, so $u_1\in C(K)$, but by item (iii) the element $u_1u_2$ is conjugate to $u_1$, so there is $g\in G$ such that $u_1u_2=gu_1g^{-1}$, so $u_1u_2=gu_1g^{-1}\in gC(K)g^{-1}=C(gKg^{-1})=C(K)$, so $u_2\in C(K)$, but by (ii) we may assume that $u_2\in C_1$, but $u_2\neq u_1$, so looking again at the elements of $C_1\cong Z_2\times S_3$ then all involutions except for $u_1$ are outside $C(K)$, so $u_2\notin C(K)$, reaching a contradiction.

Therefore $|K|=1$, so the action is effective (faithful).